How can I avoid overusing her/she or the character name when describing character action
I'm writing a story and my writing style involves lots of paragraphs describing what's happening and less dialogue. Which I'm sure isn't uncommon, but I noticed that I tend to overuse her, she, and the character's name. Sometimes I can get away with it, but I really want an alternative way to correct this issue. For reference, the following is a paragraph I feel has this issue. I chose one with a little more dialogue, so you can see that even in those situations I have this same problem.

The girl held an immense love for her, as she was her mother, the apple of her eye the center of her being. She wanted nothing more than to be just like her.
“Alexandria, you’ve been in here half past an hour, though I'm not surprised, you look gorgeous darling!” She swooped over to Alexandria and took her face into her hands before planting a gentle kiss on her forehead. “I woe the day you discover beautifying cosmetics. If you take this long already, I'll never see you leave your vanity!”


Do you mean rue the day?

“The girl held an immense love for her, as she was her mother, the apple of her eye the center of her being” — Not necessarily related to the pronouns as such, but this sentence doesn’t really make sense as written. The phrase ‘the apple of her eye’ would usually be used for the daughter being the apple of the mother’s eye, not the other way around; so “she was her mother, the apple of her eye” makes the reader think you’re switching subjects mid-sentence a second time (are you?). ‘Half past an hour’ and ‘leave your vanity’ also sound quite unusual…

@Ben (1) Fair enough. (2) There are two she’s – the girl (A) and someone not further specified (B). Assuming A is the child and B the mother, the subject switches from A to B in “The girl [A] held an immense love for her [B], as she [B] was her [A] mother”; in which case the mother was the apple of the daughter’s eye (unusual). If A is in fact an older girl and B is her (presumably very young) daughter, then there is no subject switch; but mother is still the apple of daughter’s eye. (3) I didn’t say it cannot, only that it usually isn’t. Context may disambiguate.

An answer, but not to the question asked: I see no problem with the pronouns, but lacking context and other information (which probably exist already, but not quoted here), it is not at all clear if the "girl" talks about her own mother, or if the "girl" talks as a mother about her own daughter. I read the paragraph with both meanings, and it makes pretty much equal sense. Just consider the problem for children: "In a room there are 2 mothers, two daughters, a grandmother and a granddaughter. How many people are in the room?"

"The girl held an immense love for her, as she was her mother" << Since both characters are women, this gets confusing really quick. The two characters are clearly "The girl" and the first "her", but then I cannot tell which of the two characters are referred to by "she" and the second "her", respectively. Is "The girl" the mother or the daughter of the other character?

@Ben The second switch (not technically a subject switch since there isn’t a new verb phrase, but an antecedent switch, at any rate) would be if ‘the apple of her eye’ is intended to mean that the daughter is the apple of the mother’s eye, as it would generally be assumed to be. Then it would have to be seen as, “A held an immense love for B, as B was A’s mother, [A being] the apple of B’s eye”, with a switch back to A as the antecedent. To me, ‘the apple of her eye’ dislikes going ‘upwards’, and my brain fights against a reading where the mother is the apple.

Definitely, here the problem is rather the fact that there are two female protagonists, and it quickly gets confusing. You can use their names, and other ways to refer to them: the daughter/the mother, the elder (name)/the younger (name), etc. But don't overdo it, just make sure one clearly understands who's who.

FWIW, the phrase "apple of one's eye" very strongly implies an elder/younger relationship; particularly parent and child, with the child being the "apple" (pupil) of the proud and loving parent's eye. It is seldom used in reverse. One idiom that can apply in either direction, a parent's love for her child or a child's love for her parent, is "the light of her life".

There really is nothing wrong with using pronouns frequently to refer to your characters. Pronouns like her are among the most frequent words in English for exactly that reason: we use them a lot. They are unavoidable. Because of their commonness we, as readers, tend to "overlook" and ignore them. While a repetition of any less common word (like apple) will become noticeable and might grate on our minds, the repetition of pronouns during a scene that describes what a person does is normal and therefore imperceptible.
By the way, did you notice that I repeated to in the first sentence of my answer? Or did you feel that I should have replaced one of the three occurences of pronouns in the preceding paragraph because I used it too often? No? Well, that's your answer, then.

In my experience what is far more noticeable than consistent use of names and pronouns is a conspicuous underuse of them. Sometimes an author seems compelled to come up with a new adjective-noun combination to describe a character every paragraph or two, and that's far more noticeable and distracting!

@Carcer — oh, yeah.  Either the author picks some nominal for the character (“the unknown stranger” or “the mailman” or “Bob”) and repeats it over and over — or else comes up with a fresh description and you are wondering if this is a new character altogether.    In Marathon Man William Goldman has two unnamed characters he calls “the bull-shouldered man” and “the broad-shouldered man” and it’s so grating.

As Ben’s answer says, there is nothing wrong with frequently repeated pronouns. Pronouns are ‘invisible’ and we rarely notice them at all.
What is important, especially if you feel like you’re using a lot of pronouns, is making sure that your pronouns are used clearly. If there are multiple people of the same gender involved, having many pronouns can lead to ambiguity if you’re not careful, and while frequent pronouns will fly under the radar, ambiguity is something readers almost certainly will notice.
Take the first two sentences of your quote as an example:

The girl held an immense love for her, as she was her mother, the apple of her eye[,] the center of her being. She wanted nothing more than to be just like her.

There are clearly two people involved here, but because they’re both female and both referred to as she/her, it’s hard to tell who is who. Perhaps you’d already introduced their internal relationship earlier on, in which case the reader might not be confused; but reading this snippet on its own, it’s hard to avoid having to backtrack and read again to figure out what exactly is going on.
We learn in the following sentence that one of them (presumably the daughter) is called Alexandria; for the sake of argument, let’s say the other is called Catherine. Now let’s replace the pronouns with names in two different ways to illustrate the ambiguity:

Alexandria held an immense love for Catherine, as Catherine was Alexandria’s mother, the apple of Alexandria’s eye, the center of Alexandria’s being.
Alexandria held an immense love for Catherine, as Alexandria was Catherine’s mother, the apple of Catherine’s eye, the center of Catherine’s being.

Both these readings are possible, and readers are likely to stumble and be unsure which is intended.
Additionally, there is the fact that the phrase the apple of someone’s eye generally dislikes ‘moving upwards’ in age. It refers to someone you’re very fond and proud of, someone you dote on, and it is almost always used of children (or grandchildren, nieces and nephews, younger siblings, etc.) or sometimes spouses – rarely of parents or other elders.
This means readers will intuitively expect “the apple of her eye” to mean that the daughter was the apple of the mother’s eye, rather than the other way around – but both readings above have the mother as the apple of the daughter’s eye. It is of course possible to use the expression in this somewhat unusual way, but you would normally want to make it explicit that that’s what you’re doing, to avoid misunderstanding; here, it goes in the unexpected direction implicitly, with both people involved referred to only with pronouns.
This will only add to the ambiguity already introduced in the first part of the sentence, to the point that it goes from being ambiguous to being downright confusing. Truth be told, I’m still not entirely sure who was intended to be the apple of whose eyes.
In cases like this, where repeated pronouns introduce ambiguity or even confusion, substituting a character’s name and/or rephrasing entirely becomes a necessity. Rephrasing won’t necessarily reduce the number of pronouns, but if you can rearrange the pronouns and mix them with names in a way that makes your text unambiguous, that’s all you need.
In this case, if the daughter is meant to be the apple of the mother’s eye, I don’t see a way to get rid of the ambiguity without a fairly thorough rewrite of the sentence – perhaps something like this:

The girl was Catherine’s daughter and held an immense love for her. She was the apple of Catherine’s eye, the center of her being, and she wanted nothing more than to be just like her mother.

If it is in fact the mother who is the apple of the daughter’s eye, just naming the mother will suffice (and perhaps adding a hint of the daughter’s age, just to dispel any lingering ambiguity):

The young girl held an immense love for her: Catherine was her mother, the apple of her eye, the center of her being. She wanted nothing more than to be just like her.


Great answer, +1 !
